# Terraform dynamic block content in conditional way

Tags: terraform

I have this `terraform` dynamic block as below:

```
  dynamic "backend_http_settings" {
    for_each = var.backend_http_settings
    content {
      name                                = lookup(backend_http_settings.value, "name")
      port                                = lookup(backend_http_settings.value, "port")
      protocol                            = lookup(backend_http_settings.value, "protocol")
      cookie_based_affinity               = lookup(backend_http_settings.value, "cookie_based_affinity")
      probe_name                          = lookup(backend_http_settings.value, "probe_name")
      trusted_root_certificate_names      = [lookup(backend_http_settings.value, "trusted_root_certificate_names"), null]
      pick_host_name_from_backend_address = lookup(backend_http_settings.value, "pick_host_name_from_backend_address")
      request_timeout                     = lookup(backend_http_settings.value, "request_timeout")
    }
  }
```

And the values for `var.backend_http_settings` are as follows:

```
backend_http_settings = [
  {
    name                                = "apimPoolGatewaySetting"
    port                                = 443
    protocol                            = "Https"
    cookie_based_affinity               = "Disabled"
    probe_name                          = "apimgatewayprobe"
    trusted_root_certificate_names      = "whitelistcert1"
    pick_host_name_from_backend_address = true
    request_timeout                     = 180
  },
  {
    name                                = "vm"
    port                                = 80
    protocol                            = "Http"
    cookie_based_affinity               = "Disabled"
    probe_name                          = "vm"
    pick_host_name_from_backend_address = true
    request_timeout                     = 180
  }  
]
```

But look at that `trusted_root_certificate_names`, in the second block, it doesn't have that value. So how can I conditionally render that (remove or add) `trusted_root_certificate_names` inside the `content` ?

Because I can't pass `null` as the value as it doesn't take it as null. So how can I do this?

Comment: which resource are you trying to create ? is this AWS Apigateway ?

Comment: How did it go? The issue still persists?

Answer (score 1):

Since `trusted_root_certificate_names` is list, you can remove it as follows:

```
 trusted_root_certificate_names      = lookup(backend_http_settings.value, "trusted_root_certificate_names", null) != null ? [backend_http_settings.value["trusted_root_certificate_names"]] : null
```